# Arranging array results from a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm making a brochure generator based on inventory in a database.  Due to the way the on-paper brochure looks, the order of items display will not match the way mysql_fetch_array works.  Each user chosen category holds four items in a 2X2 grid.

```
Category 1 ---------Category 2
[1]  [2]   ---------[5]   [6]
[3]  [4]   ---------[7]   [8]
Category 3 ---------Category 4
[9]  [10]   ---------[13]   [14]
[11]  [12]  ---------[15]   [16]
```

I've already created a basic table as a placeholder for the items in this pattern.  This is my query to retrive the items.

```
$query = "SELECT t1.*, image_path FROM flyer_item AS t1
LEFT JOIN product_images AS t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id WHERE id_page = '".$id_page."'";
echo $query."<br>";

$result = mysql_query($query);
echo '<h3 class = "splitter">Items</h3>';
//-create while loop and loop through result set
//Due to the unique item arrangement patter, we fill
//an array with the fetched array results.
$iArray = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $iArray[] = $row;
    $square = $row['square'];
    $item_name = $row['item_name'];
    $sales_info = $row['sales_info'];
    $link = $row['image_path'];
    $sku_item_number = $row['sku_item_number'];
    if (empty($link))
    {
        $link = '../imagen/no_imagen.gif';        
    }


}
```

One page can hold up to a maximum of 24 items, all following the pattern mentioned above to make sure items are in their respective categories.  I'm contemplating making another database table called Categories that will store its four items, but is there a way I can use the second array, iArray, to store the number indicating where the items should go?

The actual table looks like this, to match the original document.

```
<table width="100%" border="1" bordercolordark="#000000" bordercolorlight="#000000">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $category1; ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $category2; ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Item 5</td>
    <td>Item 6</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Item 7</td>
    <td>Item 8</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $category3; ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $category4; ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Item 9</td>
    <td>Item 10</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Item 13</td>
    <td>Item 14</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Item 11</td>
    <td>Item 12</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Item 15</td>
    <td>Item 16</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $category5; ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $category6; ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Item 17</td>
    <td>Item 18</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Item 21</td>
    <td>Item 22</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Item 19</td>
    <td>Item 20</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Item 23</td>
    <td>Item 24</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: FYI nowhere in your question have you shown a query. All I see is table "structure" and PHP code.

Comment: Will each category always have exactly four items? You say that each page can store 24 items, so I assume that there can be 6 categories on each page - in that case, do 5 and 6 appear at the bottom of the page, or on the right?

Comment: If your only problem is that you don't know how you can get 4 items for each category and then move on to the next category: Try iterating over the array elements with `for($i = 0;...` and calculate the "category index" with `floor($i/4)`.

Comment: This is correct.  Each category is guaranteed to have four items.  There are really two different kinds of pages.  The "front" page has a fancy header, and that takes up space, so those only have four categories and 16 items.  Additional pages have more space, and therefore have six categories and 24 items total.